# How do I call an abstract method from a non-abstract class in Java?

Tags: java, abstract

I have Five Classes:

BankApp:

```
public class BankApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BankDatabase acctDatabase = new BankDatabase();

        acctDatabase.createCheckingAccount("Test Name", "123-45-6789", 20000.0f);

        acctDatabase.applyInterest();

        acctDatabase.print();
    }
}
```

BankDatabase:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class BankDatabase {

    ArrayList<BankAccount> list = new ArrayList<>();


    public void createCheckingAccount(String name, String ssn, float bal) {

        BankAccount account = new CheckingAccount(name, ssn, bal);
        list.add(account);

    }

    public void createSavingsAccount(String name, String ssn, float bal) {

        BankAccount account = new SavingsAccount(name, ssn, bal);
        list.add(account);
    }

    public void print() {

    Collections.sort(list, (BankAccount a, BankAccount b) -> {
        return Float.compare(b.bal, a.bal);
    });

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        System.out.println(list.get(i));

    }

    public abstract void applyInterest();

}
```

BankAccount:

```
public abstract class BankAccount {

    protected String name;
    protected String ssn;
    protected float bal; 
    private String account;

    public BankAccount(String name, String ssn, float bal) {

        name = this.name;
        ssn = this.ssn;
        bal = this.bal;
        accountNumber();
        System.out.println("Successfully created account for " + name + ". Account Number: " + account);
        if(!ssn.matches("^(\\d{3}-?\\d{2}-?\\d{4})$")) {
        System.out.println(name + " has an invalid SSN!");
        }
        System.out.println(name + ", Balance $" + bal);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { 
        return "Name: " + name + ", Account #: " + account + ", Balance: $" + bal;
    } 

    public abstract void applyInterest();

}
```

CheckingAccount:

```
public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount {

    public SavingsAccount(String name, String ssn, float bal) {
        super(name, ssn, bal);
    }

    @Override
    public void applyInterest() {
        bal = (float) (bal * 1.05);
    }

}
```

and SavingsAccount:

```
public class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount {

    public CheckingAccount(String name, String ssn, float bal) {
        super(name, ssn, bal);
    }

    @Override
    public void applyInterest() {

        if(bal >= 10000.00) {
            bal = (float) ((bal - 10000.00) * 1.02) + 10000;}
        }    
    }
}
```

I want to call applyInterest() from BankApp but, I can't because BankDatabase is not abstract. I can't make BankDatabase abstract because if I do, then I couldn't instantiate BankDatabase. So, my question is: how do I call applyInterest()?

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  If a class contains an `abstract` method, that means it *must* be an `abstract` class.  Or to put it more simply, you cannot instantiate a class with abstract methods.  What are you actually trying to achieve here?  (i.e. why are you trying to make `applyInterest` abstract, even though there are no subclasses, *and* trying to call it?)

Comment: If you want the method to do nothing by default, you can remove the `abstract` modifier and add an empty body to it.

Comment: Is there anyway I can still call applyInterest()? (i.e. making it into a normal method that masks the method in BankAccount)

Comment: What do you mean by "masks the method in BankAccount"?  These are two unrelated classes.

Answer (score 0):

That method in BankDatabase should not be abstract.  I think you want to do this:

```
public class BankDatabase {

    private List<BankAccount> accounts = new ArrayList<>();

    // Add a BankAccount; leave the type creation outside this method.
    // Polymorphism is your friend; use it.
    public void addAccount(BankAccount account) {
        if (account != null) {
            this.accounts.add(account);
        }
    }

    public void applyInterest() {
        for (BankAccount account : this.accounts) {
            account.applyInterest();
        }
    }
}
```

A few other points:

1. Think about an AccountFactory for creating savings or checking accounts (aka virtual constructor)
2. Magic numbers are a very bad idea.  Take those constants out of your accounts and make them variable.  Interest rates change, don't they?

Comment: I don't think he wants to apply interest to all of them at the same time. This is obviously classwork, don't give him the answer and turn him in to a help vampire, give him guidance so he can get to the answer on his own! :)

Comment: Hey man, nice ad hominem. Anyways, sorry that I tried to spread knowledge on bit manipulation and how handy it could be. It's cute how you think everyone cares as much as you do about rep :)

Comment: coolstorybro.jpg You're the cancer that stops people from trying to be a part of the community, and the reason why stackoverflow will inevitablly fail.

Comment: It wasn't a stupid comment, and even if it was, it was an extremely immature, condescending, and elitist way of "calling someone out".

Comment: @duffymo: The tone in your comments here is completely uncalled for.

Answer (score -1):

You need a method to return the BankAccount you're trying to apply the interest to.

So, in your list of BankAccounts you need to find the account.
Seach by ID or name. From there, you call a search method on your list to return the bank account, and from that you can .applyInterest to it.